# After downloading Android Studio, I have 1.9 GB or memory left, is that going to be a huge issue in the future?

Tags: android-studio, chromebook

I'm trying to learn programming. I found a course I'm interested in which covers basic programming, Kotlin, and uses Android Studio. I downloaded AS on my Chromebook (I have linux beta installed) and was left with 1.9 GB of memory left. I have no idea what that says about the path ahead of me. Is that going to turn into a massive roadblock?

I have enough money to get a very basic laptop, I even already know which one I'd get. Is that advisable in this case? I work full time, so it's a big deal if I have to devote time to hunting down the alternative, harder way of doing things. Although, if I learn something valuable from that, then it's worth it.

Comment: I understand you have not come across all the Android studio ram memes running around. https://amp.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/f49pcj/android_studio_ram_killer/

Comment: sounds about right